# Best way to monitor a range of cells and produce an alert based on their value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that HR is using to track employee attendance and automatically calculate attendance points (which are then used to issue warnings, terminations, etc.). It's working great but I want to upgrade it so that when a certain threshold of points is reached (or possibly several different thresholds) an alert would be shown to the user letting them know that a warning needs to be issued. It would also be helpful if the name of the employee (from column B) and the number of points could be shown in the alert box.

I can get the ui alert to show based on the value of one cell, what I'm having trouble with is how to expand that to monitor several cells (all in the same column). The way I have it set up now, let's say Employee A has 10 points so an alert pops up letting the user know. I have that set up as an onChange function. The issue with that is that anytime I make a change in another cell I'm being constantly reminded of a warning I've already issued. I did also try changing the range to include all employees and changed getValue to getValues but that array I am not sure how to monitor for changes to the values.

```
function checkPoints() {
  // Fetch point totals
  var pointsRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Employee Mgmt").getRange("J13"); 
  var pointTotals = pointsRange.getValue();
  // Check points
  if (pointTotals >= 9){
    Browser.msgBox('Attendance warning needs to be issued', Browser.Buttons.OK);
  }
}
```

Ideally, when HR inputs an attendance infraction they should be notified immediately if that caused an employee's points to reach a certain threshold and would notify them of the employee, what type of warning needs to be issued (verbal, written, termination, etc). An email would also be sent to the HR manager to keep them in the loop (that I am confident I could handle).

Comment: You have two problems: You need to loop over the array from `getValues()` (search for for loops in the google-apps-script tag, you'll find plenty of examples), and you need to have some way to determine if a warning has already been issued (you can do this by marking and reading from another column in each worker's row, for example)--if you need more specific information, post an example spreadsheet that shows your problem

Comment: _The issue with that is that anytime I make a change in another cell I'm being constantly reminded of a warning I've already issued._ Why not creating a column/row for logging Alert codes? You also mention your trigger is `onChange`  which seems odd for this kind of alert; why not onEdit(e) instead?

Comment: Mixing the suggestions from Tedinoz and sinaraheneba, Iwould suggest you have an `onEdit()` function that, when a user's points reach the threshold you've set, writes to a particular column in the same row something like `WARNING`, and then you can check that column and print the users into the `msgBox` to display all the users who have the warning status.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I was mistaken, it was set up as onEdit. I ended up adding a section a few columns over to record when different warnings are given (verbal, 1st written, 2nd written, termination). I also researched looping through the array which I think I can handle. I'm guessing that at this point what I need to do is use create a script that would run onEdit that would pull the values (number of points, warnings already given, etc.) from the cells, check against the warning values to determine what warning would be next and use offset to get the employee name.

Comment: Congrats. **Looping**: Unnecessary here, I think. Use [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) in onEdit(e). They identify the row & column, even sheet, edited. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57642867/1330560). **Codify alerts**; A = verbal, B = 1st written, etc. Much easier to compare values.  **Logic**: First test whether the edit was for an attendance issue; only then do you need to check the alert status, points, etc. **UI Alert** Plenty of stuff on SO; also brief example in the earlier link. Post a comment if you have a problem.