# Is it possible to protect a range of cells when a checkbox is checked in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Sorry for the complicated and possibly confusing title. I am currently developing a spreadsheet on Google Sheets for my co-workers. I'm working in a train transportation company. I made a checklist which includes items like 'Air Conditioner' or 'Doors', 'Lights', etc. After they finish checking the Done or Not Done boxes, I want them to check another box such as 'I checked the tools mentioned above carefully and confirm that the boxes that I checked are real', like a signature on a formal paper. When the person checks this box, all the upper boxes will be protected. I had these spreadsheet physically, and I want to do these to save from papers. I already have a script like:

```
function onEdit(e){
   let protection = e.range.protect();
   protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
   if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
     protection.setDomainEdit(false);
   }
}
```

But I know that this script locks every cell after edited. In order to avoid any risks (such as accidentally checking the 'Done' box instead on 'Not Done'). I think that this idea will be helpful for the train drivers since they don't have computers and enough time while they're monitoring and leading the train at the same time. Thank you so much for all your helps!

EDIT: Thanks to @doubleunary and @TheLegend's comment, I created a sample spreadsheet with no script linked to it: [The Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26H8T.png)

Comment: I think what I need is a simpler version of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57601229/how-to-freeze-a-range-of-cells-when-a-checkbox-is-clicked) but I am a starter with this kind of scripting, so I'm not sure how to simplify it.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data.

Comment: I really appreciate you instant reply! @doubleunary

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: `I want them to check another box such as 'I checked the tools mentioned above carefully and confirm that the boxes that I checked are real', like a signature on a formal paper.` You can protect the Done/Not Done range, but allow to only show a warning, but edit. Then Google sheets will automatically show a popup: " This range shouldn't be accidentally edited. Are you sure?"

Comment: @TheMaster Okay, thanks for the beneficial comment. I’m currently using a mobile phone, so I’ll also add the photos of the spreadsheet when I switch to my computer. Also, I checked the links you sent, so I’ll also try to be more descriptive while uploading the photos. Lastly, thank you a lot for letting me know that my email address could be accessed by public, so I’ll remove the link. Instead, I’ll insert images. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @TheMaster I couldn’t quite understand what you meant by ‘You can protect the Done/Not Done range, but allow to only show a warning, but edit.’ Do you mean that I can display a message before they can edit the checkbox? If so, that isn’t exactly what I was looking for. I’m looking for an idea which prevents people from editing a checkbox after confirmed, like a submission form.

Comment: Have you considered [creating a form](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6281888) instead of sharing a spreadsheet for data input?

Comment: @meta6483 Yes, that was what I was saying. I understand your main request, but wasn't that one of your requests as well - to prevent editing accidentally - to show something before finalizing?

Comment: @doubleunary Yes, I've thought of creating a form, but the company has two types of co-workers who need to monitor each other's reports, so I think that it's easier to use tables instead. Also, they'll need to submit the form for each departures and since my manager doesn't want the co-workers to submit more than one report per departure, I guess it's impossible for me to do both in a form.

Comment: @TheMaster I have thought about that as well but the suggestion I gave my department was the one I asked in the question, but I'll try your idea (which is a lot practical than mine) as plan B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an [installable "on edit" trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable), like this:

```
/**
* Protects the whole sheet when the checkbox in cell B7 is ticked.
* The account that installed the trigger will retain edit rights.
*
* Runs on an installable trigger each time the user hand edits the
* spreadsheet. To manually create an installable "on edit" trigger, see:
* https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable
*
* @param {Object} e The "on edit" event object.
*/
function onEditTrigger(e) {
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error(
      'Please do not run the onEditTrigger(e) function in the script editor window. '
      + 'It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet.'
    );
  }
  if (e.value !== 'TRUE'
    || e.range.columnStart !== 2 // column B
    || e.range.rowStart !== 7) {
    return;
  }
  const me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  const protection = e.range.getSheet().protect();
  protection.addEditor(me);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: I’m currently on a mobile phone, so I’ll try it as soon as I switch to my computer. I seriously appreciate your interest. I’ll mark this as the solution when I test the script, but I truly believe that the script will run just fine. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: It really worked! Thank you so much, this will be really helpful for my company, as well as me since this is my first answered question (in fact, I only have two questions asked) thank you for showing me how a friendly platform [Stack Overflow](stackoverflow.com) is! Thanks to @TheMaster as well, who helped me developing my question. :)